# Nested classdef with or without handle?

Tags: matlab, class, handle

I am trying to used updatable object (class) in Matlab with nested class. I observe a behavior that seems to be due to the handle status.

I write the 2 classes `testA` and `testB`. `testB` is a the main class that calls the class `testA` as a property:

```
classdef testB 
    properties
        objA=testA;
    end
    methods
        function obj=testB()
            obj.objA
            if isempty(obj.objA.val)
                obj.objA.val=5;
            else
                 obj.objA.val=obj.objA.val+5;
            end
        end
        function up(obj)
            obj.objA.val=obj.objA.val+6;
            obj.objA.val
        end
    end
end
```

Firstly, `testA` is a handle class.

```
classdef testA < handle 
    properties
        val=[];
    end
    methods
        function obj=testA()
        end
        function set.val(obj,tt)
            obj.val=tt;
        end
    end
end
```

When I create `testB` object two times

```
tt=testB
tt=testB
```

I observe that the `val` property in `testA` is not reinitialized (`val` in `testA` keeps the previous value). I am not sure but it seems to be due to the `handle` feature. The method `tt.up` increase the `val` property in `testA` as expected.

Secondly if I change the `testA` class to a value class.

```
classdef testA  
    properties
        val=[];
    end
    methods
        function obj=testA()
        end
        function obj=set.val(obj,tt)
            obj.val=tt;
        end
    end
end
```

In this case the successive calls of `tt=testB` create each time a new instance of `testB` with a new instance of `testA`. Unfortunately in this case the `up` methods does not work as expected (the new computed value of `val` is not stored in the object).

A solution could be to consider `handle` class for `testA` and force to delete it before fully initialize the `testB` object. However I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [documented behavior](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/specifying-properties.html#brqy3km-10): in your `testB` definition, `obj=testA` is evaluated only once, when the class definition is loaded. All instances of the class will have a reference to the same handle class object.

Just [below on same documentation page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/specifying-properties.html#br18hyr) you'll see that you should create a new instance of `testA` in the constructor for `testB`, if you want a different instance of `testA` for each instance of `testB`:

```matlab
classdef testB 
    properties
        objA
    end
    methods
        function obj=testB()
            objA = testA;
            % ... further initialization
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! I have not seen this point in the documentation.

Comment: @Guuk: I know, there's a lot of documentation and it's not always easy to find the relevant parts.